# Validating a radio button group client side?

Tags: xpages

I added a required validator for a radio button group but it does not seem to work.   I understand this might be an issue with radio button groups?

I found this solution here

http://www.bleedyellow.com/blogs/patpicos/entry/xpages_xp_validaterequired_not_working_on_radio_buttons_not_radio_button_groups1?lang=en_us

but it uses server side validation and the rest of my form is using client side and both look different.  I would much rather them look the same.   Is there anyway to validate a radio button group client side?

Comment: I found Stephen's blog http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/shwl-7qg88xand see he recommends server side validation anyway for "real" validation. Should I just continue with my server side validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validate required will work for radioGroup control.It doesn't work with radio controls grouped by a groupName.

The below CSJS code may help you to see any one of the radio controls in a group are checked or not (put it in onclick event of a button).

```
    var isChecked = false;
dojo.query('input[name$=groupName]').forEach(function(node){if(!isChecked){isChecked = node.checked;}});
if (!isChecked)alert('no value checked.')
```

Comment: You can put the above code in the onclick event - client of Submit button. If no radio button was checked, you can return false. Then in onclick event - Server, you can call Save(), to save all data sources.